Run vanilla JUnit Tests in a Maven Tycho build
I have a maven/tycho project with some sub-modules. Usually, I run all my tests within the OSGI environment with the tycho-surefire-plugin. But now, I have a test that must explicitly be executed as a vanilla JUnit test.
I tried setting up a separate maven module which uses the maven-surefire-plugin. My test classes are compiling fine, but no tests are actually being executed. The maven-surefire-plugin logs "No tests to run.".
Is it even possible what I am trying to achieve? Do I need to consider something specific?

The maven-surefire-plugin is not capable to resolve the dependency of an Eclipse plugin. tycho-surefire-plugin can also run non-UI with only some instead of all other plugins: see https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#executing-plug-in-unit-tests-with-tycho If this is not enough, please describe exactly why this technically doesn't work for you. (Running JUnit tests for an Eclipse plugin that don't work in an OSGi framework doesn't make sense, does it?)

@howlger I added the dependencies via pom.xml which seems to work fine (at least compiling succeeds). My test is a bit special: it needs a dependency which only works if it is running in a non-OSGI environment.

What is the exact technical reason that this dependency does not work in an OSGi framework?

The dependency is mariaDB4J. It searches the java classpath for some required resources. I think that it may be possible to extract and configure them manually, but I would much rather use the plugin as it is.

It is unclear how your code is structured (JUnit tests in a separate project for an Eclipse plugin project?) and how you build it (what's in your pom.xml file(s)? do you use mvn clean verify?). Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Using maven-surefire-plugin in a Maven/Tycho build may not work. When you do mvn install then also the artifacts built with Maven/Tycho are in your local Maven repository and can be used as dependencies in other Maven builds.

A solution for your mariaDB4J problem might be using maven-resources-plugin to copy resources e.g. from a different Maven module to where there are needed/expected.

@howlger yes, this is possible. MariaDB4J allows to specify a custom location for the required files. But still: it is not as nice as using it plainly. Also, I am curious if using plain JUnit tests is possible at all ;).

Plain/vanilla JUnit tests run fine also in an OSGi environment via the tycho-surefire-plugin. What you want is to run those tests in a non-OSGi environment. I don't know if this is possible in a single Maven build, but I'm pretty sure that it is possible to run the tests in a separate build that depends on what was build before with Maven/Tycho. Again, please provide a minimal reproducible example.
